# Angular ngx-ECharts - Change color of one specific heatmap cell

Tags: angular, typescript, echarts, ngx-echarts

As the headline suggests, I am searching for a method to change one specific cell in a [echart](https://xieziyu.github.io/ngx-echarts/api-doc/) [heatmap](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=heatmap-cartesian). Through a search in the [api](https://echarts.apache.org/en/api.html#echarts) I found the possibility to change the `itemStyle` via the `setOption()` API-method, but it changes the color for all entries of a given `series`. To be more specific, I would like to change the color of a given field on x-position and y-position.

Example of the final functionality:
The following picture shows the `demo-heatmap` and a blue field on `x-pos: 12a`, `y-pos: friday`, which turned blue after clicking on it (example picture).
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a second series containing only the specific heatmap cell:

```js
series: [
    {
    ...
    },
    {
        type: 'heatmap',
        data: [[0, 1, 1]],
    },
]
```

and use a second visual map which only operates on the second series (keep in mind that visual maps are applied in the order they are given):

```js
visualMap: [
    {
    ...
    },
    {
      seriesIndex: 1,
      show: false,
      inRange: {color: 'lightblue'},
    }
  ],
```

Here is an [example](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=heatmap-cartesian&code=PTAEAcCcFMBdYJbUgWgQcwHYHsYCgBjbTAZ1lAAtsBXSE0AXlAG09R3QByARgCYBDTgBou3QSM4DhXAMziuAFnmcArMoBs4th04B2ZQA5lATmXcADGbHDt7Hr3DSejiQ6cyXiz6pe2u6711vA29jbwtw7kc8AF0AbjwQCBh4JFQMHHwiUnIAE34AT3omVg4uAGV-WFp8gqcAMUgEWqcAFQpaEhahP04AdWhczGguwrbqEe6uAFliKc5y6kwW2ISkqDhEZDQsXGhCYjJQfNh-RhZmcxEr0BUYkUuRbif7lhvea9fH0BlPh5uFH83iIVEDvuowTddJCRAYYaBjPCLEjnqBeF8bnwRAoMU9fqBuLiCYCCUTuKCfmSIaAcf8ntDQOoyXCaWTEay6WibjIibxUTzObwPmjefi7g9UVCvqjJdKRMLzHKfmDUSTFRKQSqRNT1SxUQzdcxUSzDaj2aanjdxXqnqj0RqCcL7TaCfimQ7uCTjErybafdT3S7uAzdD6WQYfey-EreFaY6jrUb5cLQw7ePjncwFS8HsKZV8nWDhfjDcK1QXNaBS9qiyIDRXQCaG-aG8jKbnbfLW3nW_jvR3ibDWxSLK2A62GYm8yyp092bOuXWG3zscuncv8bSWCWlw98fyvhmwfiS4fscfK4a3RfQPW97Cc9uRC37wS46_uKqz47d0_XU8t2YfcSW4AU_19R1v24al-3AycoJnKCoyveUbkDID5S_V8hVXbD9y-NVH2YECRDA4j5TBElTweElyxoytCXoxlKLrFjGzY9lMxAgECM7DkWBA9cmNA3CBIA0TyIJEdAJA6lo2EhlGLEglw14gl5zU2NSM0_VNOLTTqJYCl3i-EciIpBVTNI7SHgpOijMvKzmKrJy7wc9iRVs58wRHHivIJfN_KxW4nJEt9QpJRMRwpVN3Ogv0goZdCRybIKNP8rT23cld-OYCyhOywzmB1Ii5LBalLIeakiupeziscqqaxcxrb3Kh9mpYGC2rfUq-MNOSCvq_9SRaz0bM6p47K-OSdWm-luu4VKJvU7rMqUoacszCrBoqt0YhiPwADoAFt-HAAAKAAzJYCEQYhQHOhBYGgY6AEpQAAbz8FJaEwFgnpeo1XgB47LmB57QfRUAAB9oa4FBOHiPAAF9XoSbBwDuv6mC-9hYGwbAABtEHAAAuT6_HAbASCehBiHJzh8eidhkZ6dh0CaXJydxjgKGgDAKFgBmVHMABSGwyiZhmLHF7RWe0AAPABBBWEBIbm_FgApwGgBmCCqaB0FwOo2Y4E5-HJqhOlN9gSHAQmnqVmALYpspbaoAB3cnYEgCY_GRuXTYKFW1Y1yXtd1rh9eeo3IBNvxzfJ2oSBt0A7Yd2AnegF2ebKEhPe9339jKAOWdNgA3NXqH4QnpjO8nSg4XOOGOhBMHJq4_HYU6FfJ5Eu9AfXCYIahCf4AAjQnI59iZU_YXAkEwIWuCoJoAC9iFOQmJbdqfLuXzgCGgJfkB3spx-weBsGO6WVFlkvU-b23kCQEgAEllmgXuCTntOC9AS6NcSDQF_m3AASvwTA6BI4fUHkTXADMHboEFpPCYnBQClw4Jg-42hgFNBGA3PwT9QCYH4MdSOnAAAKN0KCgAAML8EgLkM-HAtY6wZnzKop1fBu2OFUF25tf5j3HtAQmYdeF_2wF7UAM9i5u3lrwl64AKD8BpurV2EiQblC1lPcREi_78FyFIgAQoTWgfdO76PdoYqRdD4GQAZpAdA49-DnRuO464h0VCvU4APFmA9MFlyIQPNhFDOGwG4Sw9gicLiYheAdEu2gDrIziEAA).